# How to load different Event source (json) for each View?

Tags: fullcalendar

Hi i have a calendar which must load a different JSON source of events for each view. ie, A brief source for "Month" (only a max of 3 items per day cell), then more detailed sources of data for both "Day" and "Week".

I was thinking i could capture when a view has loaded and based on which view, call `removeEventSource()` to remove the previous event source then `addEventSource()` to add the current view's related data and refresh. 
Is this the only way to do something like this?  If so... how do i detect that the view has finished loading so i can call `getView()` to inturn load the appropriate event source?

I've seen there is `loading()` callback but i don't think this is what i need, i want to know when the whole calendar is complete loading not just the current data.

Thanks for any help

EDIT: The only other way I can think to do this is remove the DAY/WEEK/MONTH fullcalendar buttons and replace with my own which reloads the php screen with a variable appended say `&calLoad=month or &calLoad=day` i can then load with a different json feed but this is obviously a less optimal way of doing things.

Comment: Surely someone has dealt with this issue? I want to load a different json feed depending on which view is loaded day/week/month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funnily enough I just [posted an answer to an entirely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941552/14750) that happens to be the solution to this. I used the `addEventSource`() and `removeEventSource()` methods, as the OP considered.

```
<script>
var fcSources = {
    courses: {
                url: base+'accessfm/calendar/courses',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                error: function() { alert('something broke with courses...'); },
                color: 'purple',
                textColor: 'white',
                className: 'course'
            },
    requests: {
                url: base+'accessfm/calendar/requests',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                error: function() { alert('something broke with requests...'); },
                textColor: 'white',
                className: 'requests'
            },
    loads:  {
                url: base+'accessfm/calendar/loads',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                error: function() { alert('something broke with loads...'); },
                color: 'blue',
                textColor: 'white',
                className: 'loads'
            }
};
$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    firstDay: 1,
    theme: true,
    eventSources: [ fcSources.courses, fcSources.requests, fcSources.loads ],
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        if (lastView != view.name){ // view has been changed, tweak settings
            if (view.name == 'month'){
                $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', fcSources.loads )
                                  .fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );;
            }
            if (view.name != 'month' && lastView == 'month'){
                $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', fcSources.loads );
            }
        }
        lastView = view.name;
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

viewDisplay is trggered when view has changed 
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewDisplay/

then you can check view.name atribute

Comment: if anyone is still looking - viewDisplay has been deprecated in favor of [viewRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this example :)

I was not able to make this ( in above code the events array ) work for me, but i figure out another way to add event sources using some of the code you provided.

This is my logic:

My primary source of events is this(this is the events source from the default examples of Fullcalendar):

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',
                dataType:'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                  
                    'acc':'2',                      
                },
                success: function(doc) {                            
                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround
                    var Editable = null; //Workaround  
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {                       
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "false") //Workaround 
                                Editable = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "true") //Workaround 
                                Editable = true; //Workaround                       

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: Editable
                        });                             
                    }); 


                    //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.folgas );
                    //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.ferias );       
                    //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');               
                    callback(events);
                }
            });     
        }
```

Now i needed it to add more sources and to do this ouside the calendar (next to the date variables from fullcalendar examples) i made a variable like the code above, but with ajax calls similar to my primary: )

```
var othersources = {

   anothersource: {               
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',               
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                  
                    'acc':'7',                      
                },          
                success: function(doc) {    

                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround
                    var Editable = null; //Workaround  
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {                       
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "false") //Workaround 
                                Editable = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('editable') == "true") //Workaround 
                                Editable = true; //Workaround                       

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: Editable
                        });                             
                    });                         

                    callback(events); //notice this
                }
            });     

        },                
            cache: true,
            //error: function() { alert('something broke with courses...'); },
            color: 'green', //events color and stuff
            textColor: 'white',
            //className: 'course'
       }     
 }
```

The following code is similar to the above and is part of the calendar proprietys (inside calendar variable):

```
            eventSources: [ othersources.anothersource ],           

viewDisplay: function(view) {    
        if (view.name == 'month'){
       // alert(view.name);
            //calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.folgas );
            calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', othersources.anothersource );
            //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); //Notice i'm not doing the refetch events. And its working for me. but i'm calling thi elsewhere, every time i make an action. So you must figure it out ;)           
        }
```