# FullCalendar - add variable number of events to eventSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, fullcalendar

I am implementing a FullCalendar as a vacation calendar for my team. I would like each member of the team to have a different color for their items, so I am pulling the list from the database with an ajax request. I was wondering how to combine this list into an array of events to make an eventSource array. I looked at this link: [How to load different Event source (json) for each View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575935/how-to-load-different-event-source-json-for-each-view) but it had a defined set of events.

So if I have list of 5 employees in my database, and a different color assigned to each of them in said table, how could I pull the list, populate an array, and set that as my list of events. (the # of employees can change, so I can't just cap it at 5).

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: tdate,
        editable: false,
        eventSources: [
           for(var i=0;i<fcSources.length;i++){
                               fcSources.eventnum + i;
                           }
        ]
    });
```

Obviously this isn't working. The prior piece basically populated the array of events into fcSources.event1, fcSources.event2, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the list is a json file, you can use that and you don't have to do any for looping. Or take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941596/106866)

Comment: Oh nice. Think I totally missed the point of that other link. Now I can loop thru my eventsource array and add them with AddEventSource. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just populate a single JSON feed with all employee data? That supports different colors for events.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev how so? the only way I can see to do it is: `events: {url: 'vacation.cfc?method=vacay&returnformat=json', color:blue, type: 'GET', error: function() {alert('there was an error while fetching events!');}},` This makes it so I only have one color for every person and event (vacation) returned by that method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26934653/1810243 has an example of setting color per event.

Comment: Thanks for the info @MikeSmithDev So I see that you are manually setting the info in your answer there, i.e. url, color, etc. So what I need to do is make an ajax request, get the list of employees and colors to an array, then loop thru that array to populate what you have in your answer there. Testing now to see if I can dynamically do that with a loop inside the `events` code.

Comment: What I was getting at is just build that `color` into your JSON feed. No need for looping. It's doable that way too, just easier if the feed has the color data in it, then nothing else to do.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Wow I am dumb. You are correct; just built it into my JSON feed as another element and poof! it worked. Thanks so much for your help. I did actually get building an array of event objects to kindof work, but they only showed the first day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at @MikeSmithDev's answer above, just build [color] as an element into the JSON feed. So instead of having my JSON feed just be [title],[start],[end],[id] I also added [color] and built it into my query.

Then you can just use:

```
events: {
    url: myurl,
    type: 'GET'
}
```